# How to pass updated database (my bookmarked data) from a view to another tabbaritem 's view populating in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Please guide me in passing data. My storyboard contains two tabbars. In first view I put two buttons by selector in navigationbar that add and remove objects from bookmark. It's not a problem until here. When I change my tabbar to show updated bookmark database in tableview I see duplicated object in rows. I used

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

and

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

but still it shows duplicated object. this is my second class code to show updated data

```
@implementation BookmarkViewController

@synthesize data , tableData , tblView ;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    sql = [[SQLiteManager alloc]initWithDatabaseNamed:@"datadic.db"];
    bookmarkQuery = @"SELECT EN FROM table WHERE BOOKMARK IS 1";
    res = [sql getRowsForQuery:bookmarkQuery];
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[res valueForKey:@"EN"]];
    NSLog(@"%@" , tableData);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    indexRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc]init];

    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CELL";

    myCell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];


    if (myCell == nil) {


        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: myIdentifier];
    }
    [tblView reloadData];
    myCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    myCell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return myCell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [tableData count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tblView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:YES];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are instantiating a spare copy of UITableView every time [cellForRowAtIndexPath] is called. You call both [reloadData] as well as [deleteRowsAtIndexPaths] on this copy, which doesn't do anything.

Try this revised code (I'm assuming BookmarkViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController):

```
@implementation BookmarkViewController

@synthesize data , tableData , tblView ;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    sql = [[SQLiteManager alloc]initWithDatabaseNamed:@"datadic.db"];
    bookmarkQuery = @"SELECT EN FROM table WHERE BOOKMARK IS 1";
    res = [sql getRowsForQuery:bookmarkQuery];
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[res valueForKey:@"EN"]];
    NSLog(@"%@" , tableData);
    [tblView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    indexRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];

    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CELL";

    myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier];


    if (myCell == nil) {


        myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: myIdentifier];
    }

    myCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    myCell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return myCell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [tableData count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                   withRowAnimation:YES];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: i edit my code as u guide me and add this `[self.tableView reloadData];` to my code but still my tableview show wrong and duplicated object.this "BookmarkViewController" is a subclass of UIViewcontroller that i put like here `@interface BookmarkViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate>` in my ".h"

Comment: forexample:when i run my app first time every data is shown correctly in tableview.after that i open my tabbar that  add/remove buttons are there when i click the button to add new bookmarked word(forexample "spade"), my tableData mutable Array log shows like 2015-04-09 13:27:39.577 `m[40674:919914] (
    wool,spade,
    "corn ; maize",
    flax`  
)  . but in table view shows like this** (
    wool,
    "corn ; maize",
    flax ,  flax)** .

Comment: thank you but unfortunately it did n't work.i add `[tblView reloadData];` instead of `[self.tableView reloadData];` but it's like before.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to say what's going on without seeing how BookmarkViewController is being set up and used.

Comment: i agree.it's hard.i appreciate you because you tried to solve my problem.